# mismatch redirect uri when calling "google_auth_oauthlib" library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

my client-secret:

{"web":{..."redirect_uris":["https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground","https://cloud-project.ew.r.appspot.com","https://localhost","http://localhost"]}}

I run some CLI python code from the `cloud terminal`.
The code calls "google_auth_oauthlib" library.

```
    auth_flow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file=client_secret_json_file_fath, scopes=scopes)
    auth_flow.run_local_server()
```

and I get in the cloud terminal an authentication url.
When I click on it I see a consent window with "uri mismatch" error. Not explaining what's the expected uri.

[image]

How can I fix this?
I saw these, but adding "localhost" didn't help.

[Google OAuth error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320021/google-oauth-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-in-python)

Comment: Click error details then watch this https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ?si=j9CTYszlBHC51ck7

Comment: Linda's video should solve your problem. Refer to the [documentation](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html) to read the client flow configuration including the `rediect_uri`.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks! It resolved this pop up. But I'm getting into `connection refused by localhost` now. Is it because this flow cannot be run from a google cloud shell?

Comment: Your code is for an installed app the consent screen will be prompt on the cloud server.   Either your code is wrong or your approach is hard to tell without seeing a full example of your cide